# Postresql Trailing date for a givn date

Tags: postgresql

How do I get a 5 trailing weekday for a particular day (for example if my current date is '20220727' ( wednesday). I want result as  ( '20220727', '20220720',  '20220713', ,'20220706', '20220629').  Is it possible to get this result to be used in a subquery. Is there an inbuilt function to do this?
I will be using these dates as

```
where date(al.run_date) in ( '20220727', '20220720',  '20220713', ,'20220706', '20220629' )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `generate_series()`

```
select *
from the_table
where al.run_date::date in (select date '2022-07-27' + g.nr::int
                            from generate_series(1,5));
```

Comment: Thanks this is good

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Let me know if someone disagree or someone has a better solution.

````
(select max(run_date) -28 from public.alert_log) ::timestamp,
(select max(run_date ) from public.alert_log) ,
'168 hours')```

Thanks,
Ro
````